# why in hexpm's migrations files it use `execute` for create and drop table?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

In etco doc, it use its independent `create table` statement by `mix phx.gen.schema`.

The command is as follows:

```
mix phx.gen.schema User users name:string email:string
```

The migration file is as follows:

```
defmodule Pen.Repo.Migrations.CreateUsers do
  use Ecto.Migration

  def change do
    create table(:users) do
      add :name, :string
      add :email, :string
      add :password, :string

      timestamps()
    end
  end
end
```

But in [hexpm](https://github.com/hexpm/hexpm/blob/main/priv/repo/migrations/20140128201839_add_users_table.exs) project, the migrations file is as follows:
My question is what's the difference between them? Is etco hasn't `drop table` method?

```
defmodule Hexpm.Repo.Migrations.AddUsersTable do
  use Ecto.Migration

  def up() do
    execute("""
      CREATE TABLE users (
        id serial PRIMARY KEY,
        username text,
        email text UNIQUE,
        password text,
        created_at timestamp,
        updated_at timestamp)
    """)

    execute("CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ON users (lower(username))")
  end

  def down() do
    execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS users")
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Ecto.Migration`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto_sql/Ecto.Migration.html#module-creating-your-first-migration) has extensive documentation, explicitly stating:

> #### Change
>
> Having to write both `up/0` and `down/0` functions for every migration is tedious and error-prone. For this reason, *Ecto* allows you to define a `change/0` callback with all of the code you want to execute when migrating and *Ecto* will automatically figure out the `down/0` for you.
>
> — https://hexdocs.pm/ecto_sql/Ecto.Migration.html#module-change

For this to work, the `up` migration should be clean enough for [ecto](/questions/tagged/ecto) to figure out `down` counterpart.

---

Why is it done that way in `hexpm`? Well, legacy (the project was started before [ecto](/questions/tagged/ecto) reached any mature state,) or because authors liked explicitness, or whatever else.

Comment: When I created table again, it gives the following error message "** (Postgrex.Error) ERROR 42P07 (duplicate_table) relation "users" already exists"

Comment: I am not sure I follow what are you trying to tell me. Rollback a migration first, then retry?

Comment: Oh, I should rollback manually, not automatically. Thanks.